# why I have 2 swap paritions?

Tags: fstab, swap

I'm new in using Ubuntu,
I just installed ubuntu 12.10 and everytime I start up the pc, a message tell me that

> the  drive /dev/mapper/ubuntu-swap_1 is not ready yet or not present

.

This is my current situation:

```
sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="fa675e68-de82-4257-8960-bb312d08e113" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="NLQ7rm-qbYa-QS4y-If3b-nLaY-FHZq-Dklhr8" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root: UUID="bf5875d5-5cdd-4b08-a16e-168f75e535e9" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1: UUID="1acc7002-dc75-452d-b46f-034c03c00f5e" TYPE="swap"
```

in the `etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=fa675e68-de82-4257-8960-bb312d08e113 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/ubuntu-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

in the forum there are suggestions to change the name with uuid,but in my case in fstab there are 2 swap.

should I change it anyway?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about the last line of your `/etc/fstab` file , I mean

```
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

So If you observe it one more time , the keyword is `cryptswap1` nothing but at the time of installing Ubuntu you may have selected Encrypt your home directory option that's why only it came up into the action else it won't. That partition will mount everytime at the booting and that will help you in the Home directory encryption . No problem with that.

If you are not using encryption now then you can remove it by deleting that specific partition .

If you want to find out status of the partition then you do it with

```
 sudo cryptsetup status cryptswap1
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is little different, as per blkid command you mentioned you have one swap with named "**/dev/mapper/cryptswap1**" but in /etc/fstab, you have another swap "**/dev/mapper/ubuntu-swap_1**" (Before doing anything please check how many files /dev/mapper directory consist, by default it show you only **ubuntu-root** and **cryptswap1**)

I have a suggestion for you, run

> sudo swapon -s

and check how many swap is working in your system. If it show you output only "/dev/mapper/cryptswap1", then you can remove that /etc/fstab "/dev/mapper/ubuntu-swap_1" entry from there.

And if the output of swapon -s is like

> Filename              Type        Size    Used    Priority
>
> /dev/mapper/cryptswap1                 partition  4071420 2568    -1
>
> /dev/mapper/ubuntu-swap_1                partition    4071420 2568    -1

Then you have to turn off ubuntu-swap_1 swap partition first and then remove entry from /etc/fstab file

> sudo swapoff /dev/mapper/ubuntu-swap_1

Restart your system and ubuntu-swap_1 will gone. Might it helpful for you.

Comment: in my dev/mapper  i have  ubuntu-root criptswap1 and ubuntu-swap_1.when running swapon -s  It does not return any swap available.If running sudo cryptsetup the criptswap is active. Should I create manually the ubuntu-swap_1?

Comment: you already have one swap for Ubuntu , why you need one more again ?

Comment: theI would like to have one swap. main problem is that at ubuntu start up i got the message reported on top of my description, that means that it can create a swap , if i understand correctly.in addition if i run the sudo swapon -s command, it return no swap available.